# Implementing shared resource algo with singleton and multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, singleton

I am trying implementing something like-
  A singleton class hold some objects of type thread (classroom with 2 student objects) and there exists a class which holds some static resource(Resource.java). I start the 2 threads in my singleton class one after the other and make them to consume the static resource. This takes place in a synchronized method of the class which has resources. In the run method of the thread, i call the above-synchronized method and get output as below-

**output-**

Request for chocolate from : 0 
check if other childs available: Yes
block ends
--Student 0 finishes run!---
 
Request for chocolate from : 1
check if other childs available: Yes
block ends
--Student 1 finishes run!---

My question is that after child_1 finishes execution of the synchronized block and executes sleep(), (thread_1 sleeps for 5 sec and thread_2 for 0 sec) the other thread (child_2) should start the execution of the synchronized block before child_1 wakes up because the child_1 is not in the synchronized block and sleep time of child_1 > then the execution time of child_2. WHy is child_1 blocking the other?

**expected output-**
Request for chocolate from : 0
check if other childs available: Yes
block ends
Request for chocolate from : 1
check if other childs available: Yes
block ends
--Student 1 finishes run!--- 
**--Student 0 finishes run!---**

How do i accomplish this.

My code file--
Singleton class (ClassRoom.java)

```
public class ClassRoom {

private static ClassRoom instance = null;
private static Student s[];

public static ClassRoom getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new ClassRoom();
        initStudents();
    }
    return instance;
}

private static void initStudents() {
    s= new Student[2];
    s[0] = new Student(0,2,5);
    s[1] = new Student(1,2,5);
}

public Student getStudent(int i) {
    return s[i];
}
}
```

Student.java

```
public class Student extends Thread {
int sid;
int max_choco;
int allo_choco;
private Resource resource= new Resource();

public Student(int i, int j , int k) {
    sid = i;
    allo_choco = j;
    max_choco = k;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        resource.requestChocolate(sid, 2);
        Thread.sleep(Math.abs(1-sid)*5000);
        System.out.println("--Student "+sid+" finishes run!--- ");
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public int getSid() { return sid;}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return sid+" : "+allo_choco+" : "+max_choco;
}
}
```

Resource.java

```
public class Resource {

private static int total_chocolate = 10;

public void requestChocolate(int id, int request) {
    synchronized (Student.class) {
        System.out.println("Request for chocolate from : "+ 
                           ClassRoom.getInstance().getStudent(id).getSid());
        if(request <= total_chocolate) {
            System.out.println("check if other childs available: "
            +((ClassRoom.getInstance().getStudent((id+1)%2).getSid()>-1 
            && ClassRoom.getInstance().getStudent((id+1)%2).getSid()<3)?"Yes":"No")); {
            }
            total_chocolate-=request;
        System.out.println("block ends");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Request cannot be granted");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Runner class(Test.java)

```
public class Test {

 public static void main(String args[]) {
     ClassRoom room = ClassRoom.getInstance();
     for(int i = 0 ; i< 2; i++) {
         room.getStudent(i).run();
     }
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're **not** starting the `Thread` correctly. Your call to `run()` is as synchronous as possible :). Change it like this and it will work:

```
ClassRoom room = ClassRoom.getInstance();
for(int i = 0 ; i< 2; i++) {
        room.getStudent(i).start();
}
```

What will happen by calling `start()` is that the JVM will spawn a new thread and then call the `run()` method into that thread. Obviously since you overridden `run()` that means your code will execute. The difference is that if you call `run()` directly then all the magic inside `start()` is lost and the call executes in the same thread as it would have happened by calling any other method.

Some other potential mistakes:

- In this situation is desirable to make `Student` implement `Runnable` rather than extending `Thread`. Do a Google search to understand why.
- Your ClassRoom singleton is not thread-safe which could create bugs later on if you cannot guarantee that only one thread uses `ClassRoom`. Add synchronization to `getInstance`.

Comment: I was making a call to run() instead of start() that was causing the problem. I corrected it and got the program working. Thanks man!!!!
I spend a long time figuring why it wasn't working.....Thanks again!